# Можете посоветовать плагин для донатов PayPal?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, поиск-библиотек, paypal

Может кто-то пользовался плагином для донатов PayPal (платный или бесплатный), который соответствует требованиям:

1. Посетитель заполняет поля Email, Amount и Comment (в идеале возможность добавлять/менять поля).
2. Нажимает на Pay что переходит на оплату через PayPal.
3. Посетитель сайта получает кастомный Receipt уже после того как оплата была произведена.
4. Чтобы можно было кастомный Receipt редактировать (Donation Receipt Editable).

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй [NOWPayments](https://nowpayments.io). Кроме крипты (донат, продажи), они работают с фиатом.